# Ajax (to php function) jquery called on radiobutton click leads javascript function to be unreferenced

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have two radiobuttons that represent different products, and once one of them is clicked, I want to update the price on the website depending on the selected product. The problem is that the onclick works fine where i just have a function showing alerts depending on the radiobutton which is checked, but as soon as I add the ajax query code, i get the following error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: pricecheck is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick". I have tried many things to solve this issue, but haven't found anything yet.

The code is as follows:

This is the radiobuttons:

```
 <input onclick="pricecheck()" type="radio" id="stdclick" name="stdmaxselect" value="standard"
         checked></br>

  <input onclick="pricecheck()" type="radio" id="maxclick" name="stdmaxselect" value="max" >
```

This is the javascript code that triggers properly with the above html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function pricecheck() {
        if (document.getElementById("stdclick").checked){
alert("execute standard query");


        } else if (document.getElementById("maxclick").checked){
alert("execute max query");

        }
    }
 </script>
```

And this is the Javascript that doesn't trigger at all due to the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function pricecheck() {
        if (document.getElementById("stdclick").checked){
alert("execute standard query");
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {pricechangefunction: "success", productid: "5922"}
            success: function(result) {
alert(result);
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = result;       

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=5922" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
         });

        } else if (document.getElementById("maxclick").checked){
alert("execute max query");
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {pricechangefunction: "success", productid: "7360"}
            success: function(result) {
alert(result);
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = result;   

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=7360" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
         });
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Is the script just statically served to the client or are you appending it to the DOM at some point?

Comment: have you tried giving full path like http://{your domain}/functions.php

Comment: @buffy it is just statically served to the client, i just put it through a raw JS script in wordpress visual composer just above the relevant html.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki yes i tried that as well but the issue seems to occur before this.

Answer (score 0):

try it with total jQuery.

```
jQuery('#stdclick').on('click', function(){

//you can get value of raido button here and use it in the code if required.

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {pricechangefunction: "success", productid: "5922"}
            success: function(result) {
alert(result);
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = result;       

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=5922" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
         });
});

jQuery('#maxclick').on('click', function(){

//you can get value of raido button here and use it in the code if required.

jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {pricechangefunction: "success", productid: "7360"}
            success: function(result) {
alert(result);
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = result;   

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=7360" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
         });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have tried it and the structure works but as before, as soon as I add the ajax query then nothing hhappens anymore not even if i put alerts. before the AJAX queries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go for a structure like this, which works fine when you run it:

```js
$(function() {

  function makeAjaxRequest(productId) {
    console.log('making ajax request for product with id: ' + productId);
    // jQuery.ajax({
    //     url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
    //     type: "post", //request type,
    //     dataType: 'json',
    //     data: {
    //       pricechangefunction: "success",
    //       productid: productId
    //     }
    //     success: function(result) {
    //       console.log(result);
    //     }
    //   });  
  }

  $('#stdclick').click(function() {
    makeAjaxRequest("5922");
  });

  $('#maxclick').click(function() {
    makeAjaxRequest("7360");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="stdclick" name="stdmaxselect" value="standard" checked>
</br>
<input type="radio" id="maxclick" name="stdmaxselect" value="max">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I just tried this but nothing was displayed on the console. It might be an issue with how im implementing the script? I am using visual composer in wordpress and just adding the JS before the relevant html.

Comment: Ok actually it now works, i just moved the script after the html, so sorry haha, thanks for your help! I will try implementing the ajax now and see

Comment: As soon as I add the jQuery:

jQuery.ajax({
         url: "/functions.php", //the page containing php script
         type: "post", //request type,
         dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          pricechangefunction: "success",
           productid: productId
         }
         success: function(result) {
           console.log(result);
         }
       });  

Basically nothing happens anymore, not evven the first console message.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution, and would like to post it in case someone else has the same issue. Basically, and I should have mentioned it, as I am in wordpress and the function is located in functions.php, I needed to use the pre-built AJAX system in order to call the function in functions.php properly. Both examples above in the answer work to trigger the click but I just had to switch the JS to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery('#stdclick').on('click', function(){

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'pricechangefunction',
            // add your parameters here
            productid: "5922"
        },
        success: function (output) {
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = output;       

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=5922" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
        });
});

jQuery('#maxclick').on('click', function(){

jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'pricechangefunction',
            // add your parameters here
            productid: "7360"
        },
        success: function (output) {
document.getElementById("pricedisplayfield").innerHTML = output;       

document.getElementById("buttonorder").innerHTML = '<a style="background-color:#dc2a1b; color:#ffffff;" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-custom" href="?add-to-cart=7360" title="">SOLD OUT</a></div>"';           
}
        });
});

 </script>
```